# Trouble finding the velocity of a projectile launched from a height

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, projectile-motion

The following question has been giving me trouble for a while now, it states

> A particle is thrown with speed $10 \space \text{ms}^{-1}$ from a point  $2\space \text{m}$ from the ground, at an angle of  $45°$ above the horizontal. What is the speed of the particle when it is at a height of $4 \space \text{m}$  for the second time in its motion?

I have tried the following,

$$v^2-u^2=2as \iff (v\sin(45))^2=(10\sin(45))^2+2(-10)(2)$$
$$v=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sin(45)} \implies v=4.47\space \text{ms}^{-1} $$

But I did not get the correct answer of $v=7.75\space \text{ms}^{-1}$, similarly I tried using the equation $s=\frac{1}{2}at^2+ut$  to first find the time taken and then plug it into $v=at + u$ to yield the velocity however this was to no avail.

Where am I going about wrong, I have a sneaking suspicion that it is to do with the value of $s$.

Comment: When you found the solution to $s = \dfrac{1}{2}at^2 + ut$, which of the two solutions did you use?

Comment: @StephenDonovan I used the greater value of $t=1.023 \space \text{s}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the horizontal direction, where you have no acceleration, $v_x=v_{x0}=v_0\cos45^\circ$. In the vertical direction $$v_y^2=v_{y0}^2-2gh=v_0^2\sin45^\circ-2gh$$
Then $$v^2=v_x^2+v_y^2=v_0^2-2gh$$
Notice that the angle does not matter. You could have gotten this from the conservation of energy.

Comment: @StephenDonovan They ask for the velocity, not for the vertical one. In fact, if you plug in the numbers, you will see that my answer agrees with the expected solution.

Comment: I realized this, that's why I deleted the comment. My apologies, I misread the question.

Comment: Should it not be $v_y^2=v_{y0}^2-2gh=v_0^2\sin^2(45^\circ)-2gh$

Comment: @Filthyscrub That should be correct, yes